# Facebook Connect with Phonegap Build not including cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js

Tags: facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am using Phonegap Build and Hydration

My config does include the plugin

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect">
    <param name="APP_ID" value="my_appId" />
    <param name="APP_NAME" value="my_namespace" />
</gap:plugin>
```

On build.phonegap.com it is showing it my app under the plugins tab...

```
Installed 3rd Party Plugins
com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect        0.4.0

Installed PhoneGap Plugins
org.apache.cordova.camera       0.2.3
org.apache.cordova.console      0.2.3
org.apache.cordova.device       0.2.3
org.apache.cordova.dialogs      0.2.2
org.apache.cordova.geolocation      0.3.2
org.apache.cordova.globalization        0.2.2
org.apache.cordova.media-capture        0.2.3
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen     0.2.3
org.apache.cordova.vibration        0.3.3
```

I'm not specifying which version of PG to use so it is running 3.1.0

In my index.html file, in the head I have

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="device.js"></script>
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script src="cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
<script src="facebook-js-sdk.js"></script>
```

**Here is the part that I can't seem to find anyone else having a problem with:**

In my deviceready callback I am testing for `typeof CDV == 'undefined'` to test and it's coming back as undefined. As far a I can tell is that `cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js` isn't getting included correctly.

Am I correct that `cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js` and `facebook-js-sdk.js` do not need to be copied into my www directory because they are included there by PGB?

Btw, I'm testing on Android Nexus5

`<access origin="*" />` is in my config

Comment: If you have the liberty to use phonegap inappbrowser plugin give this [library a try](https://github.com/caiovaccaro/phonegap.facebook.inappbrowser)

Answer (score 0):

I could never get CDV to work correctly on my Android emulator/phone.

However, I did get FacebookConnectPlugin.js to work, which is also [included](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/www/phonegap/plugin/facebookConnectPlugin/facebookConnectPlugin.js) in the same [official PhoneGap/Cordova Facebook plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin).

There are two version of this file -

1. One that you include in your root www/js folder
2. Another which is loaded by PhoneGap from the plugin folder after you deploy to platforms/android (I believe this is handled by cordova.js).

The second one overrides the JS SDK calls with native ones, so it degrades gracefully when you run in a browser.

For an example *that actually seems to work*, see the www folder in the [develop branch](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tree/develop).

e.g.

```
var getStatus = function () { 
                facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus( 
                    function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) },
                    function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
            }
```

Comment: would you mind posting a step-by-step of how you got this up and running? I downloaded the phonegap-facebook-plugin-develop directory but I'm not sure how to make it work with an app now. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: or even a hint would be super helpful, if you have a couple of minutes. Thanks again

Comment: Try following a getting started guide to create a Cordova/PhoneGap app.  I used http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/ (Ionic is a thin Cordova wrapper). Next, follow the relevant "Automatic Installation" section here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin. Finally, try copying over the example above.  Prepare for a bit of debugging/googling if you get errors, it took a bit of messing.

Comment: By copying the example, do you mean just replacing the www folder of the HelloWorld app with the one above? If so, then I should be able to get this to work with Phonegap Build as well, correct?

Comment: Yes, take your pick between PhoneGap/Cordova/Ionic.  And yes about copying the www folder.

Comment: Thanks. Did you get it to work on your Android phone, or just your browser?

Comment: Both; had some problems on the emulator though, not resolved yet ("lost connection" error). I also created an AngularJS wrapper if it helps anyone: https://github.com/dunksmith/facebookConnectPlugin-angular

Comment: Cool, last question. If I'm signed on to the Facebook app on my phone, shouldn't this plugin already know that I'm logged in when I click "Get Login Status"? It's returning 'null' right now (and the issues isn't permissions because I've used it and approved the app in the browser)

Comment: Yes - sorry I can't be more helpful. I found the android log useful, run "del log.txt" then "adb logcat -d > log.txt".